# word 2007 add-in installation does not work with word 2010

Tags: vsto

I have developed a word 2007 add-in using Visual Studio 2010, everything is working fine in the Development environment , but when I install the add-in on a end-user computer the following exception appears  :

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = Intel {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 3.1', phase BuildList
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 3.1':
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '3.1': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Windows Installer 3.1' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'VSTORuntimeVersionInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'VSTOR40\vstor40_x86.exe'
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'VSTORuntimeVersionInstalled' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'Intel': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of checks for command 'VSTOR40\vstor40_x86.exe' is 'Install'
Running checks for command 'VSTOR40\vstor40_x64.exe'
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'VSTORuntimeVersionInstalled' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'AMD64': true
Result of checks for command 'VSTOR40\vstor40_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
EULA for components 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\Mtaraby\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD4EF7.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\Mtaraby\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD4EF7.tmp\"
(12/5/2011 7:48:33 AM) Downloading 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=182804' to 'C:\Users\Mtaraby\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD4EF7.tmp\'
Download completed at 12/5/2011 7:48:38 AM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\Mtaraby\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD4EF7.tmp\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned -2146762749
Subject form unknown
(12/5/2011 7:48:38 AM) Downloading 'VSTOR40\vstor40_x86.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158917' to 'C:\Users\Mtaraby\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD4EF7.tmp\'
Download completed at 12/5/2011 7:48:42 AM
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\Mtaraby\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD4EF7.tmp\VSTOR40\vstor40_x86.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned -2146762749
Subject form unknown
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)', phase BeforePackage
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\Mtaraby\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD4EF7.tmp\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned -2146762749
Subject form unknown
Error: Setup has detected that the file 'C:\Users\Mtaraby\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD4EF7.tmp\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' has changed since it was initially published.
```

Note:-

1 - the end-user computer is having .Net Framework 4.0

2 - the client has word 2010

Is there any prerequisites for Word 2007 add-in should be installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shold install the below 2 installer

1-Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86) Setup

2-Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup